# Application design: NH-session management, generic repository, ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, session, fluentvalidation

Having defined a `domain model` I want to figure out how to do the rest of work.

---

**DATA ACCESS LAYER**

I had read before that it is not necessary to code own `UnitOfWork` implementation over `ISession` (thogh I found a much information on how to do it pretty well). So I'm quite confused.. I have repository interface like this:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T: AbstractEntity<T>, IAggregateRoot
{
    T Get(Guid id);
    IQueryable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> predicate);
    IQueryable<T> Get();
    T Load(Guid id);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Remove(T entity);
    void Remove(Guid id);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Update(Guid id);
}
```

Where in the concrete implementation there are two options:

*OPTION A*

Is to inject `ISessionFactory` thru constructor and have something similar to:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : AbstractEntity<T>, IAggregateRoot
{
    private ISessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Repository(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
    public T Get(Guid id)
    {
        using(var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            return session.Get<T>(id);
        }
    }
}
```

*OPTION B*

Is to use `NHibernateHelper` class

```
using(var session = NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession())
{
    return session.Get<T>(id);
}
```

Where `NHibernateHelper` is

```
internal sealed class NHibernateHelper
{
    private const string CurrentSessionKey = "nhibernate.current_session";
    private static readonly ISessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static NHibernateHelper()
    {
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static ISession GetCurrentSession()
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        ISession currentSession = context.Items[CurrentSessionKey] as ISession;

        if(currentSession == null)
        {
            currentSession = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
            context.Items[CurrentSessionKey] = currentSession;
        }

        return currentSession;
    }

    public static void CloseSession()
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        ISession currentSession = context.Items[CurrentSessionKey] as ISession;

        if(currentSession == null)
        {                
            return;
        }

        currentSession.Close();
        context.Items.Remove(CurrentSessionKey);
    }

    public static void CloseSessionFactory()
    {
        if(sessionFactory != null)
        {
            sessionFactory.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

What's option is prefered?

Why(besides the injection)?

If I use option `A` where do I place configuration of `ISessionFactory`?

Should it be placed somewhere in `ASP.NET MVC` project? How?

Thank you for reading the monster-question! Your guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Please break the question about Validation out into it's own question. Asking multiple things within a single question is generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to handle injecting dependencies with mvc is somewhat version specific but it *always* helps to use a real Dependency Injection (DI) container.  However you slice it, this solution will need you to Inject an ISession into the Repository rather than an ISessionFactory.  This allows your DI container to manage the lifetime of the session properly.

Assuming you're using Asp.Net MVC 3 and dont have an attachment to a specific DI container already, fire up your [Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/) console and type:

```
install-package Ninject.MVC3
```

This will go, download Ninject (which is a DI container) and configure your mvc application to use it.  It will also create a file ~/App_Start/NinjectMVC3.cs which is where you'll configure your dependencies as such.

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<ISessionFactory>()
        .ToMethod(c => new Configuration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory())
        .InSingletonScope();

    kernel.Bind<ISession>()
        .ToMethod((ctx) => ctx.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession())
        .InRequestScope();

    kernel.Bind<IRepository<>>().To<Repository<>>();        
}
```

The first statement tells ninject that when something requires an ISessionFactory, it should lazily initialize NHibernate and create one.  This session factory is then to be held as an application-wide singleton for the lifetime of the application.

The second statement tells ninject that when something requires an ISession, it should get an instance of ISessionFactory and call OpenSession().  This Session is then reused within the scope of the request and destroyed at the end of the request.

The third statement tells ninject that when something requires an IRepository of any type, it should just new one up using it's built in logic to resolve dependencies.

From here you can write your code as follows and everything should just work.

```
public class WidgetController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRepository<Widget> _repository;
    public WidgetController(IRepository<Widget> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
}
```

With regards to the Repository I'd like to point you to an excelent blog post [Repository is the new Singleton](http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton)

Comment: Yes I've read the article before. But I can't just understand all of these discussions around. Isn't it sufficient to have repository with query method like that `IQueryable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> predicate)`? Thank you!

Comment: Also I wanted to ask in what scope the session binding should be created? Request (one instance per web request)?

Comment: the Session should be bound at the request scope which is what InRequestScope() will do.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a read only property, on my repository, like this

```
    protected  ISession Session
    {
        get
        {
            return NHibernateSessionFactory.CurrentFor(dataBaseFactoryKey);
        }
    }
```

My NHibernateSessionFactory works like [this](https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Sharp-Architecture/blob/master/Solutions/SharpArch.NHibernate/NHibernateSession.cs).

Answer (score 1):

In web apps you should use pattern NH session per web request. I think you should have only one session per web request and your repositories should use this single session.
To implement this you need to write IHttpModule which will open session, begin transaction and bind session as ambient (current) session when request begins and end transaction and close session when request ends. You also need to set current_session_context_class to "web". Then your Repository/DAO will look like this

```
    public TEntity Get(object id)
    {
        return sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession().Get<TEntity>(id);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Best pattern with MVC and NHibernate is session per request.
steps:

1. In Global.asax add
   public static ISessionFactory **SessionFactory**;
2. In **Application_Start()** configure and build session factory:

   var config = new Configuration().Configure();
   SessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
3. In **Application_BeginRequest** open the session and bind it to
   CurrentSessionContext:

   var nhSession = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
   CurrentSessionContext.Bind(Session);
4. In **Application_EndRequest()** unbind and dispose the session

Now in your controller you can access your session invoking:

```
Global.SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
```

**EDIT:** Following @hival comment

Inside your controller handle your model in a using block and perform commit/rollback based on your logic.

Comment: You forgot to open transaction in point 3 and commit/rollback transaction in point 4.

Comment: It's better opening transaction only when needed, so in the controller. Also it's not right to commit/rollback in EndRequest because it's too late. The choice between commit/rollback is possibile only in the controller.

Comment: In this case your controller will be tied to concrete DAO/Repository implementation.